# test client in tutorial 5 of django

Tags: django-tests

while doing tutorial 5 of django, in the section Django test client every thing work fine until now but when I write this code in shell from `"response = client.get(reverse('polls:index'))"` I got some error. I am not understanding what the error is about and so not able to correct it.

Please help how to correct it.

Screen shot of error.

[image]

Screen shot of error.

[image]

this is mysite/polls/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic

from .models import Choice, Question


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'


"""
     "def vote(request, question_id):
     "   ... # same as above, no changes needed.

    def vote(request, question_id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        try:
            selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
        except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
            # Redisplay the question voting form.
            return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
                'question': question,
                'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
        else:
            selected_choice.votes += 1
            selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
"""
    def vote(request, question_id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        try:
            selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
        except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
            # Redisplay the question voting form.
            return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
        'question': question,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
    })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

this is mysite/polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

Comment: Please post all the relevant parts of your code, as well as the error traceback, as text and not as images!

Comment: @saurabh Have you managed to resolve this problem?